# Login with Facebook dialog doesn't show

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I try to use log in with facebook with SDK 3.5 but i cant get it work.

The login popup doest show up.

I use this code to start the log in process when the usre click on my button:

```
private void onClickLogin() {

        Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
            Session session = new Session.Builder(RegisterPage.this).build();
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            currentSession = session;
        }

        if (currentSession.isOpened()) {
            // Do whatever u want. User has logged in

        } else if (!currentSession.isOpened()) {
            // Ask for username and password
            OpenRequest op = new Session.OpenRequest((Activity) RegisterPage.this);

            op.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
            op.setCallback(null);

            List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
            permissions.add("publish_stream");
            permissions.add("user_likes");
            permissions.add("email");
            permissions.add("user_birthday");
            op.setPermissions(permissions);

            Session session = new Session.Builder(RegisterPage.this).build();
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            session.openForPublish(op);
        }
    }
```

And this onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent data2)
 {


        if (Session.getActiveSession() != null)
            Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
                    resultCode, data2);

        Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
            Session session = new Session.Builder(this).build();
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            currentSession = session;
        }

       if (currentSession.isOpened()) {
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void call(final Session session, SessionState state,
                        Exception exception) {

                    if (session.isOpened()) {

                        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                            Response response) {
                                        if (user != null) {

                                         facebook_name = user.getName();
                                         facebook_id = user.getId();
                                         email = (String) user.getProperty("email");

                                         Log.i("email", email);
                                        Log.i("facebook_name", facebook_name);

                                         if(isNetworkAvailable())
                                             new GetProfilePicture().execute();

                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
            });
        }

 }
```

Comment: Where is your function onClickLogin() calling??

Comment: Have you updated your manifest with all needed tags?

Comment: You can follow this source to get login work for you: https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

Comment: In general, you should add a callback to your OpenRequest. The reason for that is any errors that you might encounter along the way is passed to the callback. The only way to debug your problem is to pass in a callback, and check the exception in the call() method.